# Ravan Dahan is morally right?

Tags: ravana, brahmanas

Ravan Dahan, where effigy of Ravan is burnt, is celebrated in some parts of Bharat during Vijaya Dashami day.

Ravan, though rakshasa, **still considered as Brahmana.**
Some Puranas white of Rama, Hanuman getting Brahmahatya sin and doing expiations for that.

Now, is it morally right to burn, though in effigy form, of a Brahmana?

*[This is not about characters of Ravana or his rakshasa character justifies. It's about whether burning an image of a Brahmana is acceptable/allowed.]*

Comment: Rāma is beyond any pāpa, none affects him. Even if he kills a Brāhmaṇa, he doesn't get patita nor does he earn the doṣa of Brahmahatyā. He is a dharmavyatikramī. 
In Pātālakhaṇḍa (adhyāya 8) of Padma Purāṇa, Rāma says that he had done grave wrong by committing Brahmahatyā, but Agastya explains that Rāma had incurred no pāpa at all. Still Rāma insisted, and asked for a prāyaścitta for the pāpa (*this is clearly an instance of līlā*). And Agastya gave a sure-shot prāyaścitta for Brahmahatyā (for a king), i.e. to perform Aśvamedha.

Comment: And following this, we know, Rāma did perform Aśvamedha. In Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, Lakṣmaṇa suggests Aśvamedha, and he also mentions that Purandara did Aśvamedha to destroy his pāpa of Brahmahatyā. So, this story has śāstra pramāṇam to support it, and this also shows it to be a līlā. It's not that Rāma had committed any pāpa, but he was setting an example & behaving as a manuṣya, who is a Rāja, ought to behave, in accordance with dharma.

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to know, how is even Rāvaṇa dahana morally wrong, as per you?
You didn't provide any sound reason and opinion regarding this, in your post

Answer (score 1):

Burning Ravana effigy is probably influenced by how Lord Rama killed Ravana as per Ramopakhyana ( which is from a different Kalpa) -

> Then Rama shot that terrible weapon of unrivalled energy, destined to
> compass Ravana’s death, and resembling the curse of a Brahmana on the
> point of utterance. **And as soon, O Bharata, as that arrow was shot
> by Rama from his bow drawn to a circle, the Rakshasa king with his
> chariot and charioteer and horses blazed up, surrounded on all sides
> by a terrific fire.** And beholding Ravana slain by Rama of famous
> achievements, the celestials, with the Gandharvas and the Charanas,
> rejoiced exceedingly. And deprived of universal dominion by the energy
> of the Brahma weapon, the five elements forsook the illustrious
> Ravana. **And were consumed by the Brahma weapon, the physical
> ingredients of Ravana’s body. His flesh and blood were all reduced to
> nothingness,—so that the ashes even could not be seen.'"**"

Draupadi Harana Parva, Mahabharata.

As per Ramopakhyana, Mahabharata, Lord Rama burned Ravana alive to the point that not even Ravana's ashes could be seen.

Comment: Thanks. This explains the reasons for celebration. Question is more on whether it's morally right to do this considering Ravana is a Brahmana.